# Convert 20121004 (yyyyMMdd) to a valid date time?

Tags: c#

I have a string in the following format `yyyyMMdd` and I am trying to get it to look like this:

`yyyy-MM-dd`

When I try:

```
string date = "20121004";

Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I get the error:

`FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Would the following work or would I run into a problem:

```
private string GetValidDate(string date,string format)
{
    DateTime result;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    {
        return date;
    }
    else if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    { 
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     }
     else
     {
        return "Invalid Date Format";
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed the yyyyMMdd format in the source string?  If so, why not just use string methods to add the hyphens?

Comment: I thought about that. What is the best method for that?

Comment: There's a string-based answer below.  It seems pretty reasonable

Comment: the straight string manipulation also depends if you need any validation on the fields, too.

Comment: In your second case, you can just return `result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` no need to parse `date` again.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Just use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
string date = "20121004";

string result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This also provides the advantage of validating the date before reformatting it with the hyphens. `ParseExact` throws an exception you can catch, if the date is not in valid range, or the format does not match.

Comment: +1 DateTime.ParseExact is the correct way to handle custom formats.

Comment: Is it necessary if I know the Date is always valid? Just curious.

Comment: When dealing with dates, I personally think it is always essential to validate them before processing them further.

Comment: One last question, what is the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for?

Comment: **"throws an exception you can catch"** If you want to handle error situations, use `TryParseExact` instead of exception catching. (Exceptions should not be used for normal program flow control.)

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier - if the Date is already in the yyyy-MM-dd format, will this cause any issues?

Comment: It tells the ``ParseExact`` method to ignore specific culture setting of the current environment (e.g. the operating system). After all, you dont want your code to break only because the users OS is set to some exotic language and culture.

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier - OK, I would have just called it, `CultureInfo.WhoCares` :)

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: you're right. I assumed that those strings always come in the given format, so it really should be an 'exception' (pun indended). :)

Comment: Yes, if I start with yyyy-MM-dd, then there is no need to do a conversion. Is there a simple way to check for this before?

Comment: @Xaisoft: you should then use ``DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)`` to check if it is already in the format.

Comment: @Xaisoft: sorry, forgot the ``DateTimeStyles`` parameter. It should be ``DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)``.

Answer (score 7):

> I get the error:
>
> FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

You are getting this error because you are not telling the ToDateTime() method how to figure out to parse your string.

If you use the following method:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    DateTimeStyles style
)
```

You won't get this error.  After you generate a DateTime variable just display it in the format `yyyy-dd-mm` using the ToString() method.

```
public string ToString(
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e

**I know this basically repeats the same information as everyone else but it also provides him the ability to understand what the two methods he needs to use actually does.**

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension method I use.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a string to a dateTime with the given format and kind.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dateTimeString">The date time string.</param>
/// <param name="dateTimeFormat">The date time format.</param>
/// <param name="dateTimeKind">Kind of the date time.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DateTime ToDateTime(this string dateTimeString, string dateTimeFormat, DateTimeKind dateTimeKind)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTimeString))
    {
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    DateTime dateTime;
    try
    {
        dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), dateTimeKind);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of calling it, or explain what sort of DateTimeKinds can be used?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little ugly, but how about this?

```
date.Insert(6, "-").Insert(4, "-");
```

If you can assume you're coming in with a string representing a valid date and you don't need to do any other date-ish logic, then why go to a `DateTime` in the first place?

Comment: Maybe he needs to make sure the date is valid first. The ``DateTime.ParseExact`` just does this.

Comment: The real question is the reason his code is not working.  While this code basically will give him what he wants, it seems silly, to provide ugly code.

Comment: +1, he is just trying to add hypthens into. And wants it displayed as a valid datetime, aka correct format. He doesn't specify checking the date is valid, and as such, we can assume his date is already valid.

Comment: I counter your argument with the question that if he ultimately needs to insert two hyphens, why is he going through expensive DateTime conversion algorithms to do so? The OP said nothing about validating dates first.

Comment: @Doomsknight: I didnt downvote, but didnt upvote it either, because even though I understand your point, I think when dealing with dates or even worse with date-strings the DateTime methods should be used to validate them. But your right, it really depends on other factors that we dont know: if the date is already validated and performance is critical, it may be the better solution to just insert the hypens like Tenner proposed.

Comment: @Tenner - We cannot assume the date will be valid.  Even if he updates his question and says the data is guaranteed to be a valid date this is still ugly.

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier. It does depend really on his situation. Now he's got a broad range of answers to choose from :) I upvoted yours and his I think they are both valid, effective solutions.

Comment: @Ramhound - I don't disagree, which is why I volunteered that it's ugly. Saying a string is of the form `yyyyMMdd` rather than saying "I have a string that's an eight-digit number" to me implied that it had already been validated. I just wanted to make sure he hadn't missed the forest for the trees; I've been guilty of going through long conversions in the past when it was pointed out to me later there was a shortcut. My answer was the shortcut.

Comment: @Tenner - If you edit the post I will take my downvote away.  Since you explained it was a shortcut, I can accept it being ugly, although I hate shortcuts personally.

Comment: @Ramhound: No need to change history for rep points. Thanks for the offer, but it's still an ugly shortcut and I don't deny that. :-)